# Change prop value based on the value of a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have json objects stored in separate files. I want to pass one of the json objects as a prop into a display component, selecting the json to be passed in based on the value of a query param.

```
import React from 'react'
import _ from 'lodash'
import PageMain from '../Page'
import test1 from '../jsonData/test1'
import test2 from '../jsonData/test2'
import queryString from 'query-string'

class Page extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const location = queryString.parse(location.search)
    // Assume BrandName = 'test1'
    let BrandName = _.get(location,'brand', '')
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <>
        <PageMain brand={BrandName}/>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default Page
```

I want to pass in `test1` (referencing the imported test1 file) but I am passing in 'test1' a string.

I can't just use a ternary operator or similar because I will have a lot more jsonData.

Comment: *I want to pass in test1 (referencing the imported test1 file) but I am passing in 'test1' a string* - Not sure to understand that part.

Comment: Sorry, my phrasing is a bit confusing. No I want to pass `test1`, as in `import test1 from '../jsonData/test1'` so <PageMain brand={test1} />

Comment: You want to affect to `BrandName` a value in function of the value of `location.brand`, is that right?

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote but I need to: 1. get value of location.brand 2. Use the value in step 1 to use the imported file (of the same name) for the brand prop in PageMain.

Comment: Just use the `test1` variable instead of a `'test1'` string literal

Comment: Still not sure to get it (maybe because I am not a native english speaker). What I understood is to set `BrandName`'s value based on `location.brand`'s one. Tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Dellirium So I'm trying to use an import based on a query param without a switch statement.

Comment: What about `var possibleQueries = {test1: test1, test2: test2}` and then `<PageMain brand={possibleQueries[BrandName]}/>` basically assign your imports to a map, then read from that map based on the query. Edit: Oh I see yaya pro already suggested this.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is convert a string to module name in js.

if it was variable, you could use:
`window["variableName"]` or `eval("variableName")`

But in your example, they are modules. you should first assign modules to variables or array.

`import test1 from '../jsonData/test1' 
import test2 from '../jsonData/test2'; 
const tests = {'test1':test1, 'test2':test2};`

Then use:
`<PageMain brand={tests[BrandName]}/>`

---

But i don't recommend this. you can just put your names in an array `['test1','test2']` and fetch json data with another way, not with import.

Comment: Yes, error is Uncaught ReferenceError: test1 is not defined

Comment: @PanczerTank does it throw error as well when you use test1 directly (instead of eval(BrandName))?

Comment: No, just with the eval. It works fine if I use the import directly

Comment: @PanczerTank add after this line: `let BrandName = _.get(location,'brand', '')` this: `let Brand = eval(BrandName)`. then use `<PageMain brand={Brand}/>`

Comment: Ah I tried that before too.. Still throws the same error (uncaught ReferenceError)

Comment: @PanczerTank what about window['variableName']?

Comment: window[BrandName] didnt throw an error but it looks like it is just undefined.. it isnt using the import

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194497/discussion-between-yaya-pro-and-panczertank).

Comment: @PanczerTank oops, eval wasn't required. updated answer.